# Why does Sklearn's Naive bayes classifiers only return 1-dimentional coefficients for 2 class problems?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes, coefficients

SKlearn has a couple naive bayes classifiers, namely BinomialNB, and MultinomialNB. In both cases, the coef_ variable returns the importance weights for each feature. When there are 3 classes, coef_ is of size *3xn*, 4 classes, *4xn*, etc.. However, when it is a 2 class problem coef_ is *1xn*. Here is the code snippet:

```
return (self.feature_log_prob_[1:]
            if len(self.classes_) == 2 else self.feature_log_prob_)
```

The returned coefficients are only the ones pertaining to the second class. We can obviously get the coefficients by going to `feature_log_prob` directly, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Why is this??

Comment: where is that code from?